# new table from two different select column results (from the same table) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, select

much appreciate any help. I have a table named lifelong like presented below.

```
   id           first_meal            last_meal
0   1  2022-07-25 12:28:00  2022-07-25 20:06:00
1   2  2022-07-26 13:12:00  2022-07-26 19:09:00
2   3  2022-07-27 14:13:00  2022-07-27 20:13:00
3   4  2022-07-28 15:10:00  2022-07-28 21:22:00
```

I skip one row from column first_meal with

```
 select  f.id, f.first_meal  from lifelong   f offset 1;
```

I select all from the column last_meal with

```
 select id, last_meal from lifelong
```

Now, I need to save this two different selects form the same table as a new table

I tried union or union all, I tried to put these two selects in parenthesis - no result so far

I expect an output like below

```py
 id           first_meal            last_meal
0   1  2022-07-26 13:12:00  2022-07-25 20:06:00
1   2  2022-07-27 14:13:00  2022-07-26 19:09:00
2   3  2022-07-28 15:10:00  2022-07-27 20:13:00
3   4                  NaN  2022-07-28 21:22:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY first_meal DESC) rn
    FROM lifelong
)

INSERT INTO newTable (id, first_meal, last_meal)
SELECT id, CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN first_meal END, last_meal
FROM cte;
```

Comment: much appreciate your help. Essentially, I am skipping first row from first_meal column to eventually get time delta between first_meal today and last_meal yesterday. TO CLARIFY, you specified just two columns in a newTable, however, I have 3 resulting columns id, first_meal, last_meal. And sorry for a dumb question, but I do create the newTable beforehand right?

Comment: To clarify, what is the source of third column in your expected output table?  Your question never mentions this.  And yes, `newTable` should be created beforehand.

Comment: I am sorry for the uppercase in "to clarify"). Source of third column - so I select f.id and f.dirst_meal (skipping the first row) in the first select, and in the second select I do l.id and l.last_meal. so i expect to have almost the same table as the original, except without the first row from the column first_meal

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your expected output.

Comment: For future reference, next time you ask a SQL question include sample output.

Comment: Sorry, after more meticulous check I noticed the accepted answer  would't have my desired output - so I have edited my question.

Comment: Your question has been rolled back.  It is **not** acceptable to rewrite your question after it has already been asked and answered.  I will not provide any more help to you on this question.  If you still need help, you may ask a new question.

Comment: Fair point will do that. Thank you so very much for your help and guidance on question edit